# Spring second level cache bidirectional

Tags: spring, caching, hazelcast, second-level-cache

How the cache works for bidirectional relationship?
For example

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "directory_id")
@JsonIgnore
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
private Set<Service> services = new HashSet<>();

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
private Directory directory;
```

If I update `Directory` with relationship `Service`, the cache will update in 2 ways, because the sql query will do `update directory...` and `update service...`.

But if I update `Service` with a new `directory`, the sql will do only near service with `update service ...`, so the cache of directory is not updated, so when I get the new directory, it hasn't linked with this service, and the old one link always this service.

And I think to update the cache for `directory`, I need update the new one and the old one, so I need 3 update to update the cache, I don't know if there is a method to do it more easy or not? I want to keep this second level cache for `ManyToOne` and `ManyToMany`, how to gestion the cahe?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: nobody can respond it? or we just need to remove the cache for `ManyToMany` and `ManyToOne`?

Answer (score 0):

@yunsong-mao, I believe this is not Hazelcast or Second-Level Cache related since you confirmed that your bidirectional mapping is broken: Only one side works correctly.

I suggest you check this blog post: https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-map-bidirectional-many-one-association/

Check the usage of `mappedBy` attribute & manual assignment. If Hibernate can create the correct queries then underlying cache implementation will do the caching correctly as well.